# Can install Ubuntu on my surface pro 4 without losing my files?

Tags: surface

I am not very good with computers.

I have a Surface Pro 4 and I'd like to install Ubuntu on it, but I have no external way of backing up my files (pictures and music mostly).

Is there a way to install Ubuntu and have it run smoothly and still keep my files?

Comment: You can do a dual boot, but if you want to get rid of Windows, you're either going to have to do some weird partitioning, or just buy a cheap flash drive (you can get a 128GB MicroSD card for $30USD, and full flash drives are even cheaper). The partitioning scenarios are also for normal computers. I don't know if it's even possible to partition a Surface like that.

Answer (score 2):

This ...

> but I have no external way of backing up my files (

makes me answer this ...

> Is there a way to install Ubuntu and have it run smoothly and still keep my files?

with no.

If it is your 1st time trying to install Ubuntu you will run into problems. You will break things. You will make the wrong decision at some point in the installation. Heck, even I myself have set up tons of operating systems and make mistakes where I lost a partition or data that I did not want to remove. Backups are the safety measure you have to take to be relatively more certain you can get your files back into an operating system.

To make the answer be "yes" you must create backups and store your files on something where discissions made while installing an operating system or messing with partitions, disks or anything a level lower than the operating system itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is my strong opinion, no.

Always make a backup especially before installing a new operating system.

Backup microsoft windows so that you can reinstall windows if things get messed up. Obtain or create a reinstall media for windows such as a USB or a disk before you begin.

Also, backup your files.

If you cannot do this, you should not begin unless you do not care if you lose the files and or your microsoft operating system.

Comment: How do I backup windows? Is that the backup and restore tool? Thank you btw

Comment: @JennieRohr you are on askubuntu ;-) how to make a backup on windows is not our cup of tea. I would assume you should store the files online. Google drive or something similar.

Comment: @JennieRohr I have to agree with Rinzwind here. If you set up a Google account or gmail account, you have free cloud storage with google drive already. You get the first few gigs for free and you don't have to worry about losing it.

Comment: @JennieRohr This looks better http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-iso-image-windows-system/ Otherwise, you may be able to obtain an iso from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO and this might help http://betanews.com/2015/07/29/how-to-create-a-bootable-windows-10-usb-drive/#1